# Bold text with nested braces

Tags: math-mode, bold

I'm sure this is an easy question, but I'm not sure what the proper terminology is to search for the answer.

```
$$\textbf{k_{1,1}}$$
```

LaTeX gets all confused by this. How can I make `k_{1,1}` bold?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you mean to make the subscript `1,1` bold as well, or "only" the letter `k`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Note you should not use `$$` in LaTeX.

the answer depends on what you mean by *bold*. If you use `\boldmath` or `\bm` the k uses bold math italic. If you use `\mathbf` then it uses bold upright roman.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\[k_{1,1}\]

{\boldmath
\[k_{1,1}\]}

mathbf
\[\mathbf{k_{1,1}}\]

bm
\[\bm{k_{1,1}}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `\textbf` onto `\mathbf`.

BTW: LaTeX users will probably suggest you changing `$$...$$` onto `\[...\]`.